# How to add an asterisk symbol in a mathematical expression?

Tags: r, plot, symbols, annotate

I'm trying to annotate a plot with R² value and significance coding, but I can't pass `*` as a symbol and not as the juxtaposition operator.

I've tried `?plot.math`, here is what I tried

```
plot(1:10,1:10)
text(6,4,expression(R^2==8))
text(6,4,expression(R^2==8^{**}))
Error: unexpected '^' in "text(6,4,expression(R^2==8^{**"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `paste` inside your expression:

```
text(4,6,expression(paste(R^2==8^"**")))
```

or

```
text(6,4,expression(paste(R^2==8, "**")))
```

[image]

Comment: For any searchers who come here like me: I was trying to imitate LaTeX where `f^*(x)` looks the best and couldn't figure out how to munge the example from `?plotmath` into this (?`paste({f^, '*', }(x))`? doesn't parse); simply using `paste(f, '*', (x))` looks just fine, however.